# Android set intent class file by variable

Tags: android, variables, android-intent

I am trying to use a LayoutInflater to inflate buttons from array lists. Basically i have three array lists: one for the button text, one for the button image, and one for the class file in which it will go to when clicked. I have the text and images working when inflating the buttons however i can not get it to switch the class file when clicked. I have tried looking for a solution but i have not found anything to fit my needs. Any help is really appreciated.

Here is my code:

```
ViewGroup parent;
LayoutInflater inflater;
TextView bText;
ImageView bImage;
        parent = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.container);
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        String[] text = {"News","Chat"};
        String[] image = {"news","chat"};
        String[] link = {"Main","Chat"};
        int size = text.length;
        for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.drawable.button, null);
            int imageID = getResources().getIdentifier(image[i], "drawable",  getPackageName());
            bImage = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.ihome);
            bImage.setImageResource(imageID);
            bText = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.thome);
            bText.setText(text[i]);
            parent.addView(view);

            final String theClass = link[i];
            bText.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Intent blink = new Intent();
                    blink.setClassName(getApplicationContext(), theClass);
                    startActivity(blink);
                }
            });
            }
```

Edit: To clarify when i click any of the buttons it crashes saying it cannot find it and asking if it has been declared in AndroidManifest.xml which it is.

Comment: theClass is supposed to be the fully qualified name of the class (with package). Obtain it by calling `Main.class.getName()`

Comment: this works but how would i use my array with this?

Comment: Ah never mind what i did was put *CLASSNAME*.class.getname() in the link array instead of just the class name itself and it works now. Thanks

Comment: The only issue im having now is that one of my files dont want to do my AsyncTask when accessing it from this link. However if i access the file the old way it still works

Comment: your comment is not very clear

Comment: basically if i go to my page using Intent blink = new Intent(); blink.setClassName(getApplicationContext(), Chat.class.getName()); startActivity(blink); it will freeze on my http post request however if i go to it like this Intent chat = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Chat.class); startActivity(chat); it works

Answer (score 0):

first parameter of the blink.setClassName() is Package context. so try calling like this.

```
 blink.setClassName(packagename, fullyqualifiedactivityname);
 getApplicationContext().startActivity(blink);
```

Comment: That gives me the same result

Answer (score 0):

You should have `Main` and `Chat` Activities defined in your `AndroidManifest.xml`.
Then you need (`PKG` is the package for your Activities, i.e. `com.example.activity`):

```
Intent blink = new Intent(YourActivity.this, Class.forName(PKG + '.' + theClass));
```

Comment: this give me an error "The constructor Intent(new View.OnClickListener(){}, Class<capture#1-of ?>) is undefined"

Comment: im getting class not found

Comment: What did you use for YourActivity? I cannot tell you because your code is not there.

Comment: i put Main which is the file its all in